# Scala underScore strange behavior: error: missing parameter type for expanded function

Tags: scala, type-inference, map-function, scala-placeholder-syntax

First, this:

```
"1 2".split(" ").toSet
```

and this:

```
Set("1", "2")
```

both evaluate to the same thing, namely

```
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(1, 2)
```

Why then, when I do:

```
Set("1", "2") map (_.toInt)
```

I get as expected this:

```
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2)
```

but when I do this:

```
"1 2".split(" ").toSet map (_.toInt)
```

I got:

```
<console>:12: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.toInt)
   "1 2".split(" ").toSet map (_.toInt)
```

I checked and additional parentheses do not solve the problem.

Comment: Something is going wrong in the type checker. If you force the type to `String` everything goes well. Try `"1 2".split(" ").toSet[String] map(_.toInt)`

Answer (score 1):

The reason in in type inference when using toSet so you need to have a type hint for chain calls or split the calls.
You can find details here https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7743, https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9091

Comment: Sorry, but I think this is a problem of type variance. The `toSet` method is defined as `def toSet[B >: A]: Set[B]`. So, it as to accept all the types that are at least a `String`. Super-types of `String` do not have the `toInt` method, so there is no issue.

Comment: Quite bizarre as I repeat, these too expressions:
`"1 2".split(" ").toSet` and `Set("1", "2")`
 evaluate to the same thing.

Comment: However if you specify type directly then it works: "1 2".split(" ").toSet[String] map (_.toInt)

Comment: @GA1 using `Set("1", "2")` you are specifying to the compiler the exact type of the set, which is obviously `String`. Using the `toSet` you do not specify the exact type, but simply a "bottom" type.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be:

```
"1 2".split(" ").toSet map (x: String => x.toInt)
```

Here, I am explicitly specifying that the Set contains strings.

Chain calls have this issue in Scala where the compiler expects you to provide the type of the parameter.